# Why my function isnt working? I want to create a function to clean my dataframe and at the eand I can just call it and change the argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

filejan = "01.xls"
filefeb = "02.xls"
roomtype = {
    'Room Type Code': ['DLK', 'DTN', 'DTP', 'DKP', 'PTG', 'PKG', 'PTP', 'PKP', 'PKL', 'PTL', 'FPK', 'DLS', 'PRS', 'AVS', 'ASW', 'ASP', 'AVP', 'BFS', 'AVR'],
    'Room Type': ['Deluxe', 'Deluxe', 'Deluxe Pool', 'Deluxe Pool', 'Premiere', 'Premiere', 'Premiere', 'Premiere', 'Lagoon', 'Lagoon', 'Family', 'DL Suite', 'PR Suite', 'AS No Pool', 'AS Whirl Pool', 'AS Private Pool', 'Villa', 'Beach Front', 'Residence']
}
mtdjan = pd.read_excel(filejan)
mtdfeb = pd.read_excel(filefeb)
dataRoomType = pd.DataFrame(roomtype, columns=['Room Type Code', 'Room Type'])


def cleanJan(dataFebruary):
    dataFebruary.drop([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], axis=0)
    dataFebruary.drop(["Unnamed: 3", "Unnamed: 4", "Unnamed: 10", "Unnamed: 13",
                       "Page -1 of 1", "Unnamed: 6", "Unnamed: 2"], axis=1)
    dataFebruary.dropna()
    dataFebruary.rename(
        columns={
            "The xxx Beach Resorts Bali": "Date Create",
            "Unnamed: 1": "Name",
            "Unnamed: 5": "Room Type Code",
            "Unnamed: 7": "Arrival",
            "RESERVATION LIST": "Departure",
            "Unnamed: 9": "Rate Code",
            "Unnamed: 11": "Rate",
            "Unnamed: 12": "Company",
            "Unnamed: 14": "Segment",
            "Unnamed: 15": "Status",
        },
    )


df1 = cleanJan(mtdjan)
df2 = cleanJan(mtdfeb)

print(df1)
```

and this is the terminal

```
==============================================

WARNING *** file size (1195377) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'iso-8859-1'
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'iso-8859-1'
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'iso-8859-1'
WARNING *** file size (1228825) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'iso-8859-1'
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'iso-8859-1'
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'iso-8859-1'
**None**
==========================================
```

Comment: Those are warnings that are logged when you import your files. What do you files look like?

Comment: Pandas read my file perfectly, but my function isn’t working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many pandas functions do not modify the df it is called on, but return a modified df. Generally you should either use `inplace=True` argument if available, or use

```
df = df.some_function(..) 
... 
return df
```

construct in your function. For example, the `dropna` call in your function should be modified as follows

```
dataFebruary.dropna(inplace = True)
```

and similar for `rename` and `drop`

### Edit

Your function code looks correct except, and I missed it on the first pass, it did not return anything so `df1 = ...` would just have `df1 = None`.

So I would modify the function as follows -- first it will have a return value and second would not use `inplace` arguments, as somewhat more 'Pythonic':

```
def cleanJan(dataFebruary):
    df = dataFebruary.drop([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], axis=0)
    df = df.drop(["Unnamed: 3", "Unnamed: 4", "Unnamed: 10", "Unnamed: 13",
                       "Page -1 of 1", "Unnamed: 6", "Unnamed: 2"], axis=1)
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.rename(
        columns={
            "The xxx Beach Resorts Bali": "Date Create",
            "Unnamed: 1": "Name",
            "Unnamed: 5": "Room Type Code",
            "Unnamed: 7": "Arrival",
            "RESERVATION LIST": "Departure",
            "Unnamed: 9": "Rate Code",
            "Unnamed: 11": "Rate",
            "Unnamed: 12": "Company",
            "Unnamed: 14": "Segment",
            "Unnamed: 15": "Status",
        },
    )
    return df


df1 = cleanJan(mtdjan)
df2 = cleanJan(mtdfeb)

print(df1)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer it, but what about code structure of the function I wrote, is it correct?  Thanks

Comment: ah I missed the fact that your function actually did not return anything. see my edit, let me know if it works. As you did not provide a minimal reproducible example I can't really test. For your next question pls check out this [mcve] and [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was stuck for almost 1 night. now I can put my head at rest. once again, thank you very much.